# know if EditText empty

Tags: android

I am novice, I am trying to know if my EditText is empty to put a botton enabled or disabled. But when the EditText is empty the button continues appearing enabled. Here is my code.

```
 if((getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textcodigo)).toString().matches("")){
                 Button aceptar= (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.aceptar);
                 aceptar.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is you need `findViewById(R.id.textcodigo)).getText().toString().equals("")` and not what you currently have

Comment: I am using Fragment, it says that the method getText() is undefined

Comment: (just for curiosity): wouldn't `findViewById(R.id.textcodigo)).getText().toString().length == 0` be faster?

Comment: I dont know about it being faster or not but that is another way to check

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try

```
.getText().equals("")
```

Instead of

```
.toString().matches("")
```

Edit complete code :

```
if(((EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textcodigo)).toString().matches("")){
                 Button aceptar= (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.aceptar);
                 aceptar.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: I am using Fragment, it says that the method getText() is undefined

Comment: because you have to cast to EditText as you do with you button

(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.aceptar);

Else Android thinks it's a view not an EditText

Answer (score 0):

what you want is `.equal("")` not `matches` (which take a regex as parameter)